# DNN in TF learn, Error: "indices are out-of-bounds"

Tags: keras

I am new to TFLearn, and I am trying to implement this DNN:

```
x_train = df_train[["Pclass", "Gender", "Age","SibSp", "Parch"]]
y_train = df_train ["Survived"]

x_test = df_test[["Pclass", "Gender", "Age","SibSp", "Parch"]]
y_test = df_test[["Survived"]]

net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None , 6])
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 1)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 2, activation='softmax')
net = tflearn.regression(net)

model = tflearn.DNN(net)
model.fit(x_train, y_train, n_epoch=10, show_metric=True)
```

When I run *model.fit* , I get the error *IndexError: indices are out-of-bounds*. I suppose this issue is regarding columns's import by "name", and the network tries to elaborate the strings in the header, but I'm not sure about it.
Do I miss something obvious?
Thanks for any help!

Comment: I might be wrong, but you could try to save the dataframe as a matrix to x_train and y_train instead of saving it as a dataframe itself. If that doesn't work out, let me know. You can use df.as_matrix() or df.values to extract the array.